# Finding unique elements in nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a list **mylist = ["[amn,b,c]", "[‘a,d,e’]", "[‘f,b,e’]"]**, and I need to a single list with all the unique elements as **[amn,b,c,d,e,f]**, how can I accomplish that?

I have tried creating a function and also tried some other method, but to no avail.

***Function:***

```
mylist = ["[amn,b,c]", "[‘a,d,e’]", "[‘f,b,e’]"]

def print_list(the_list):

for each_item in the_list:

    if isinstance(each_item, list):

        print_list(each_item)

    else:

        print(each_item)

print_list(mylist)
```

**Output:**

```
[amn,b,c]

[‘a,d,e’]

[‘f,b,e’]
```

***Other method:***

```
mylist = ["[amn,b,c]", "[‘a, d,e’]", "[‘f,b,e’]"]

mylist = str(mylist)

mylist = str(mylist)

mylist = [str(x) for x in (mylist)]

mylist = set(mylist)

i = {' ', "'", ',', '[', ']','‘', '’'}

mylist.difference_update(i)

mylist = list(mylist)

mylist.sort()

mylist
```

**Output:**

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'm', 'n']
```

**Expected Results:**

```
[amn,b,c,d,e,f]
```

**Actual Results:**

***With the function:***

```
[amn,b,c]

[‘a,d,e’]

[‘f,b,e’]
```

***With the other method:***

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'm', 'n']
```

Comment: one problem is that you have quotations around your list of lists so for example `[amn,b,c]` is a string and not a list

Comment: Please feel free to look at other answers too and consider giving a vote up if useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following list comprehension, where [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) is used in order to remove unwanted characters, and the underlying lists are obtained using `.split`, and splitting by `,`.

Finally in order to obtain the unique elements from the nested list you can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to flatten the nested list, and generate a `set` from the result in order to keep unique values:

```
import re
from itertools import chain
set(chain(*[re.sub(r'[\[‘’\"\]]', '', i).split(',') for i in mylist]))
{'a', 'amn', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'}
```

Where:

```
[re.sub(r'[\[‘’\"\]]', '', i).split(',') for i in mylist]
[['amn', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'b', 'e']]
```

Comment: intereseting answer using regex. Thanks for sharing.!

Comment: @Yatu, Let us now change mylist to 
`code`
mylist = [['Action,Crime,Drama'], ['Action,Adventure,Sci-Fi'], ['Action,Biography,Drama'], ['Adventure,Drama,Sci-Fi'], ['Animation,Drama,Fantasy'], ['Biography,Comedy,Drama'], ['Drama,Music'], ['Action,Comedy,Mystery'], ['Comedy,Drama'], ['Action,Adventure,Sci-Fi'], ['Animation,Action,Adventure'], ] 
`code`

How would the code change now?

Answer (score 0):

I had to redefine the list differently because before you had 1 list with strings. If this is wrong let me know, however I am curious as to why you have a list of list-like strings.

```
mylist = [['amn','b','c'], ['a','d','e'], ['f','b','e']]
unique_list = []

def find_all_unique(input, unique_list):
    if type(input) is list:
        return [find_all_unique(x, unique_list) for x in input if x is not None]
    if type(input) is str:
        if input not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(input)

find_all_unique(mylist, unique_list)
print(unique_list)
```

**result:**

```
['amn', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f']
[Finished in 0.081s]
```

or if you need to keep your nested lists within quotations you can use this:

```
mylist = [['amn','b','c', "['r','t','x']"], ['a','d','e'], ['f','b','e']]
unique_list = []

def find_all_unique(input, unique_list):
    if type(input) is list:
        return [find_all_unique(x, unique_list) for x in input if x is not None]
    if type(input) is str:
        if input.startswith('['):
            temp_list=[]
            exec("temp_list.append(" + input + ')', {"temp_list":temp_list})
            return [find_all_unique(x, unique_list) for x in temp_list if x is not None]
        elif input not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(input)

find_all_unique(mylist, unique_list)
print(unique_list)
```

to test this I added a stringed list `"['r','t','x']"` and this should catch `r`, `t`, `x` as unique inputs

**and this results:**

```
['amn', 'b', 'c', 'r', 't', 'x', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f']
[Finished in 0.077s]
```

This will work whether it's a list of lists and stringed lists and all since the function is recursive.

Comment: Let us now change the mylist to     mylist = [['Action,Crime,Drama'],
 ['Action,Adventure,Sci-Fi'],
 ['Action,Biography,Drama'],
 ['Adventure,Drama,Sci-Fi'],
 ['Animation,Drama,Fantasy'],
 ['Biography,Comedy,Drama'],
 ['Drama,Music'],
 ['Action,Comedy,Mystery'],
 ['Comedy,Drama'],
 ['Action,Adventure,Sci-Fi'],
 ['Animation,Action,Adventure'],
]

How would the code change now?

Comment: 3 lines added and this is my result: `['Action', 'Crime', 'Drama', 'Adventure', 'Sci-Fi', 'Biography', 'Animation', 'Fantasy', 'Comedy', 'Music', 'Mystery']`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would try to substitute the `,` (comma), `'` (single quote), `[]` (open close square brackets with empty string using pattern matching. Then remove duplicates using `set` and reconstruct the list using `list` as below:

```
my_list = ["[amn,b,c]", "['a, d,e']", "['f,b,e']"]

result = sorted(list(set(([letter for word in my_list for letter in re.sub(',|\'|\[|]|\s+', '', word)]))))

print(result)
```

where

```
re.sub(',|\'|\[|]|\s+', '', word)])
```

will replace special characters in the string. For example, `['a, d,e']` to `ade`.

The comprehension based solution is technically equal to

```
result = []

for word in my_list:  # Break list of lists to lists
    word = re.sub(',|\'|\[|]|\s+', '', word)
    for letter in word:  # Process each word in the sub list
        result.append(letter)

print('results with duplicates:    ', result)  # List with possible duplicates
result = set(result)  # Remove duplicates by converting to a set

result = list(result)  # Convert set back to list without duplicates (order is not preserved)
print('results without duplicates: ', result)

result = sorted(result)
print('results in sorted order:    ', result)
```

which results as

```
results with duplicates:     ['a', 'm', 'n', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'b', 'e']
results without duplicates:  ['e', 'a', 'd', 'm', 'f', 'c', 'n', 'b']
results in sorted order:     ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'm', 'n']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dd = []
mylist = ["[amn,b,c]", "[‘a,d,e’]", "[‘f,b,e’]"]
for i in mylist:
    dd.extend([''.join(filter(str.isalnum, j)) for j in i.split(",")])
print (list(set(dd)))
#output ['f', 'a', 'b', 'amn', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```